# PF's keep state on UDP packets = security issue?

Tags: security, pf

During the last few days I've read a lot about PF as a nice alternative to iptables and a much more improved and secure way of filtering.
Nevertheless I came across the following statement which I thought could be a security issue:

> *Keeping State for UDP: 
>   One will sometimes hear it said that, "One can not create state with UDP as UDP is a stateless protocol!" While it is true that a UDP communication session does not have any concept of state (an explicit start and stop of communications), this does not have any impact on PF's ability to create state for a UDP session. In the case of protocols without "start" and "end" packets, PF simply keeps track of how long it has been since a matching packet has gone through. If the timeout is reached, the state is cleared. The timeout values can be set in the options section of the pf.conf file.*

**My concerns:** UDP does not have SequenceNr. So if an attacker eavesdrops an UDP-stream (which has already received a state in pf's state table) he could easily inject spoofed packages which will then pass the firewall, no?

Isn't that a big security issue? Or have I misunderstood something in pf's mechanism?

Comment: PF can't protect against spoofed packets in general.

Comment: If an attacker eavesdrops on a TCP connection, he could spoof the correct sequence numbers and port numbers, and pass the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: a UDP client inside the firewall initiates communication with a UDP server. The firewall creates a mapping entry to allow the conversation to continue. The attacker takes advantage of this to spoof some packets in the reverse direction.

Firstly, the packets have to have to be spoofed to look like they are coming from the server, otherwise they won't match on the remote address. They also have to be directed to the client's IP and UDP port, otherwise they don't get through the firewall. So these spoofed packets reach the client, which thinks they are coming from the server: they get received by the client application even if its datagram socket is marked as connected to the server. If the application is securely written, they end up tossed at its internal protocol level because they don't pass the integrity checks (encryption and checksums). The spoofed UDP datagrams will wreak havoc with inherently insecure applications, of course; that's no fault of the firewall.

Case 2: UDP server inside the firewall has a permanent port forward.  Of course anyone can send UDP to that; it just has to validate the packets and support only secure, authenticated sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Any other firewall will have have the same issue as PF as they all have to keep some type of 'state' to enable packets to come back in to a device behind a NAT or other kind of inbound block that lets replies though but stops new packets.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a significant risk in the scenario you describe.

An attacker able to eavesdrop on UDP traffic is already in a very privileged position. It's actually not particularly relevant that a connection is or is not listed in a connection tracking table.

From the network perspective, an attacker will normally want to a) observe traffic and data going to and from the host and b) modify some of it to suit a particular purpose. Then depending on the goal, the information could be used to impersonate the host or an entity, attempt to compromise the host, attack other hosts, etc.